# How to "widen" a mesh modeling from scratch

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, faces

[image: Widening a Mesh]

I am a 3d noob.
The captured image is taken from the back of an existing figure (Daz3d Genesis 3 in low res export) for which I am trying to create clothing. As the faces go upwards, they split in a particular "inserted diamond" way so there are more columns of faces at the top of the mesh than at the bottom. I see the diamond split occur four times in the screen capture. There is probably a correct name for this method, but I don't know it. I know I can insert vertices and bridge edges manually, but is there a shortcut? This could need to be done many times when creating a mesh from scratch. Of course I can't simply copy this mesh, I need to make my own version of it.

Comment: "but is there a shortcut?" for what specifically? You definitely do need to do this sort of thing _all the time_ while poly modelling, but you also need to do dozens of other small things. V - rip vertex. Ctrl-click adds a vertex. F adds an edge or face depending on what you have selected. Maybe worth checking out some modelling tutorials and just watch how the process goes if you're not ready to just start doing it yourself. Sorry if this sounds unhelpful, i think this question is just a bit open-ended in terms of scope of what to cover.

Comment: I thought I had worded the question rather precisely. In the StackOverflow site, in response to a question more or less identical, I would be told "there is an opensource Java library or Eclipse plugin available, download it from whoever.com." I would guess that a very significant fraction of the questions in StachOverflow are answered by, "did you know there is a tool for that?"

Answer (score 1):

Specifically addressing how to take a 'uniform grid' area of mesh and insert a new face loop ending in a single 'diamond' quad:

Select the series of vertices desired 'above' the 'diamond' location using Shift-clicks. Use Ctrl-B to bevel the selected edge loop, resulting in a triangle at the bottom. Then use Ctrl-R to loop cut down the centre of the newly created faces, such that you now have 2 new face loops running down into the 'diamond'.

[image: Animated gif showing loopcut select, bevel and loop cut as described]

This is still a "manual" process, and does need to be repeated every time one would want to perform this action, so I'm not sure if this answers the question, as the question doesn't specify how 'automatic' or how much of a short-cut is desired.

To take it further, it would be relatively straightforward to make an addon that performs these steps as a single operator, but I'm unaware if this has been done. It's somewhat subjective whether the default actions are fine- or coarse-grained enough for specific use cases, and when modelling one might very likely want to adjust the results at this fine-grained a level anyway.

Comment: Hang on!! This answer is wrong, and garbage! Using Bevel there, I created two 5-vertex N-gons. That's what I get for trying to be fancy with the shortcuts. You can do the 'proper' thing using V to rip to one side, selecting the opposing loop, F to fill , Alt-F to beautify fill, Alt-J to convert those new triangles to quads, select the triangle hole and F to fill it, THEN Ctrl-R for the loop cut. I'm curious now, surely there's a _working_ smaller set of actions.